# Executable file in xcode

Tags: objective-c

How to get the executable files from the xcode

Comment: When you ask questions on Stack Overflow, you have to be much more specific, and say exactly what you mean (and please explain it, too). That will help people answer your questions. Also, if you find that after a while, somebody has answered your question, press the checkmark button under their post ranking to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're meaning to ask how to retrieve a compiled executable from a built Xcode project, you can find it in the `build/Debug` or `build/Release` folder in the project folder, depending on the build settings of the project.